# Application of Maximum modulus theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose the function is an analytic function on $\{\omega={z:0<|z|\le 1}$}.Moreover $f$ satisfies $ |f(z)| \le \frac{1}{|z|^{1/2}}|\sin(\frac{1}{|z|})|$ for all $z$ in $\omega$. $a_n$ is the coefficient of Laurent series. I want to show that $f$ is a constant function and find the value of $f$ in the domain $\omega$. I tries to use maximum modulus theorem.$|f(z)|\le \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ for all $z$ in the domain and hence $f=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ for all $z$ in the domain.Is this valid?

Second attempt:
the function is bounded by 0 in the open disc of radius $\frac{1}{\pi}$. And then by maximum modulus theorem it is zero throughout the disk and since it is analytic after redefining then by unique of coefficient of power series, the result follows. Is this valid?

Comment: Your answer is wrong because $f(\frac 1 {n\pi})=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Can I put z=2/pi?

Comment: $\frac 2 {\pi}$ is inside the domain. But I don't understand how you are applying MMT.

Comment: How you deduce it is equal to zero for all z?

Comment: I just try to plug in different value to find the maximum value of |f|.

Comment: All I am saying is that $f$ vanishes at some point, so it cannot have the constant value $\sqrt {\frac {\pi} 2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(z)=zf(z)$. Then $|g(z)| \leq \sqrt {|z|}$ so $g$ has a removable singularity at $0$ and it becomes analytic in the unit disk if define $g(0)$ to be $0$. Hence $\frac {g(z)} z$ has a removable singularity at $0$ which means $f$ has a removable singularity at $0$. Now, since $f (\frac 1 {n\pi}) =0$ for all $n$ the zeros of $f$ have a limit point so $f$ must be identically $0$.

Comment: So the problem cannot be solved using maximum modulus theorem?

Comment: As far as I can see MMT theorem is of no use here.  @kenkenb

Comment: Could you explain the last sentence?

Comment: What happens to 2/pi?

Comment: At $\frac 2 {\pi}$ we only know that $|f(\frac 2 {\pi})|\leq \sqrt {\frac {\pi} 2}$. This is  not very useful.

Comment: could you explain how the fact that f has a limit point leads to the conclusion?

Comment: A basic theorem in complex analysis says that if the zeros of an analytic function in a domain have  a limit point then  the function is identically $0$.

Comment: Please see my second attempt for the question above.